# Generating pdf using wickedpdf and wkhtmltopdf in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am working with rails 2.3 with wickedpdf and wkhtmltopdf. While generating pdf it works fine at first time. When i am generating the pdf at second time onwards it generates RunTime Error.
It shows the error like below.
**RuntimeError in XXXXXController#xxxxxx_pdf**

```
PDF could not be generated!

Error: Failed loading page file:///tmp/wicked_header_pdf_3705_0.html?page=1&section=&
subsection=&frompage=1&subsubsection=&topage=1&webpage=foobar&time=10:55 AM&date=20/03/14
(sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors)

Error: Failed loading page file:///tmp/wicked_footer_pdf_3705_0.html?page=1&section=&
subsection=&frompage=1&subsubsection=&topage=1&webpage=foobar&time=10:55 AM&date=20/03/14 
(sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --ignore-load-errors)

QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please suggest to avoid this issue.
Thanks in advance
mayara rajesh

Comment: It looks like your issue may be the same, or related to this one:

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=656

Does removing the headers and footers stop the issue from happening?